# What is the best practise to authenticate users with rails API, devise and emberjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ember.js, devise

I found lots of websites talking about this but most seems outdated. I prefer to use JSON web token. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth - see the `jj-abrams` branch for Ember 2.0 support

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect your api then [doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) is really good gem. [How to return Doorkeeper access token as json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206483/how-to-return-doorkeeper-access-token-as-json) explains how you can use json access tokens.